# how to write a HTTP request to a file in C HTTP client program

Tags: c, http, sockets, network-programming, file-descriptor

can some one tell me how can we write a HTTP request  as below to a file (FILE *str)

GET /HTTP/1.0
Host:Google.com
Connection: close

I am Trying to write a HTTP client Program in and I got stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

`fputs("GET /HTTP/1.0 Host:Google.com Connection:close \r\n\r\n", str);` ??

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a matter of writing to a file you can use fwrite, fputs, write and other such functions. But since its a HTTP client, I think it has to be a socket write, in that case u can either implement your own socket code or can use 'curl' library to implemet this functionality.

For more reference: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html

Comment: I have already written the HTTP client to some extent but I do not whther the code works but I am attaching the code any way The only thing uncompleted is to check the End of stream of Getline() function and the process involved in it...